# How to derive the covariance formula

Tags: probability

In my book, I am given this proof:

$$ Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[X - \mathbb{E}X][Y - \mathbb{E}Y]$$
$$ Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY] - 2\mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y] + \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y]$$

I do not see why/how $$-X \mathbb{E}Y - Y \mathbb{E}X$$ becomes $$-2\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

$X$ and $Y$ are given as two random variables with finite second moments, there is no further restriction or classification upon them.

Furthermore, unrelated: Independence implies uncorrelation, but is the converse also true?

Comment: You have forgotten a bracket $$ Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\left( [X - \mathbb{E}X][Y - \mathbb{E}Y] \right)$$ I hope it is more obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}X)(Y - \mathbb{E}Y)]=\mathbb{E}[XY-X\mathbb{E}(Y)-Y\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)]$. Now using linearity of expected value, you get the right result.

The converse if false, the correlation coefficient only catches linear dependance. For example, if you have $Y=X^2$ with $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $X$ et $Y$ are uncorrelated but obviously not independant.

Comment: I forgot to take the expected value of $$-X \mathbb{E}Y - Y \mathbb{E}X$$ !

Thanks, just a silly mistake.

Comment: There is a typo. It should be [XY−X(Y)−Y(X)+(X)(Y)]. It is a plus sign instead of a minus sign at the end.